# Parametrized query for selected columns

Tags: r

I want to have a parameters on columns to select in sql query:
`select ? from my_table`

I tried it with glue_sql:
`glue::glue_sql(con, "select {x} from my_table", x=noquotes("mycolumn"))`

but the result is:

> select 'mycolumn' from my_table

instead of:

> select mycolumn from my_table

any ideas?

Comment: try `{x}` instead `x`

Comment: I make a typo. I was using `{x}` of course :)

Comment: Where is `noquotes` defined? I don't see it. Also, when I run `glue::glue("select {x} from my_table", x="mycolumn")` I get your desired output, no single-quotes. Perhaps something else is going on? (glue-1.3.0, R-3.5.1)

Comment: next type. I used `glue_sql`... is `glue` also safe when it comes to sql injection?

Comment: @MrFlick, I believe the problem is that single-quotes create a string-literal, not an identifier which makes more sense. It would be more appropriate in SQL to use double-quotes (and mssql also accepts brackets).

Comment: Good point, stakowerflol (wow, that's hard to type :-). I fashioned my comments/answer around your excellent point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to either *not* quote the identifier or quote it correctly (with double quotes). The help states:

> They automatically quote character results, quote identifiers if the glue expression is surrounded by backticks

Try:

```
glue::glue_sql(.con=con, "select {`x`} from my_table", x="mycolumn")
# <SQL> select "mycolumn" from my_table
```

If other readers wonder why single quotes are bad, the single-quotes create it as a string-literal, meaning it will be returned as *data*, not as a column header. For instance, using some table with an `Id` field:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select 'Id' from sometable limit 3")
#     
# 1 Id
# 2 Id
# 3 Id
```

(Notice no column header, a proper query might have named the string literal with `select 'Id' as somecolumnname ...`, but at that point it becomes quite clear why single quotes are not right.)

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, 'select "Id" from sometable limit 3')
#                                     Id
# 1 03E33A23-3F2C-1234-5678-90ABCDEF1234
# 2 04E33A23-3F2C-1234-5678-90ABCDEF1234
# 3 8114F80C-624D-1234-5678-90ABCDEF1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
 library(DBI)
 library(tidyverse)
  x="mycolumn"     
con%>%dbGetQuery(glue::glue("select {x} from my_table"))
```

Comment: is glue::glue also safe when it comes to sql injection?

Comment: No. `glue::glue("select * from Students where name='{x}'", x="Robert');DROP TABLE Students;--")` (https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: (For transparency, I downvoted because of the lack of protection against SQL injection. That is expressly why there is `glue::glue_sql`, so that you don't have to go down the hole of escaping/quoting/double-escaping/etc. If you switch to `glue_sql` I'll remove the -1, though I don't know that it will be answering the OP.)